# How to format my data for training and testing on Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm currently a bit stuck with creating a dataset to use in my CNN in Keras.

The network is basically the MNIST digit recognition problem but for characters in the Korean alphabet. Instead of there being 0-9 possible classes, there are 2350. Someone already did exact same thing in TensorFlow, however I'm trying to do the same thing in Keras myself (https://github.com/IBM/tensorflow-hangul-recognition).

I have a folder of jpeg files, a .csv file that maps each jpeg to its corresponding label, and finally a file with all possible labels. For example, the first few rows in the .csv are:

```
image-data/hangul-images/hangul_1.jpeg, 가
image-data/hangul-images/hangul_2.jpeg, 가
image-data/hangul-images/hangul_3.jpeg, 가
image-data/hangul-images/hangul_4.jpeg, 가
```

The first few rows in the list of all possible labels/classes are:

```
가
각
간
갇
```

[An example jpeg of the first character is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s34fq.jpg)
In my eyes I've got all the parts I need, I just need to know how I should put them all together to train the network.

Comment: Hey Patrick, welcome to Stack Overflow. Mind telling us how did that project you linked to handled this issue? Why can't you do that in Keras?

Comment: Hi DarkCygnus, in the project I linked, the programmer didn't use Keras. He put the data into tfrecords. I'm trying to use his code as little as possible so I'm hesitant to copy it!